# What does pidgin mean by "Host unknown"?

Tags: xmpp

Pidgin is telling me my XMPP account was disconnected; the error message is "Host Unknown".  What specifically does this indicate?  Can it not find the server it's supposed to connect to (one in my office)?

I can ping the server in the "Domain" account setting (under Basic) without a problem, and I even tried specifying an IP address in the "Connect server" account setting (under Advanced) without success.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Check to ensure the SSL certificate used on the server matches the domain setting on the account.

Comment: I already did.  I can ping the name of the domain specified in the account settings, as well as the name of the server it refers to, without a problem.

Comment: Is your client the only one having an issue? Is there another user with the same problem?

Comment: It's the same issue throughout the office with Pidgin.  I tried iChat from a Mac and it said the password was wrong, but the logs on the XMPP server don't show any connection attempts.  And I know the password was right.

Comment: I have Wireshark, and I don't know why I didn't think to check it before.  Running it while launching Pidgin shows it querying DNS for the account's domain, getting the proper response, and communicating with the server.  After a little bit of handshaking, the server replies with the error.  I see "service requested for unknown domain" in the text.

Comment: Would you happen to have more than one IP addresses on the server interface?

Comment: The name on the SSL certificate used on the server (which is Mac OS X Server 10.6) didn't match the domain setting.  Changing that fixed the problem.

If you can update your answer to specify that the domains hosted by the server and the name of the SSL certificate have to match the account's domain, I'll mark you as the answer.